Multivariate normal distribution using python scipy stats and integrate nquad
Let

be independent normal random variables with means

and unit variances, i.e. 

I would like to compute the probability

Is there any easy way to compute the above probability using scipy.stats.multivariate_normal? If not, how do we do it using scipy.integrate?

I can't see an obvious way to do it from the documentation.

In that case, what would be the easiest way to implement the above computation? Thank you so much.

I have converted LaTex into image to make this part intelligible. Are you sure about the limits of your integral. Written as this, first term is always equal to unity, and next variables does not fulfill the lower than condition. Have a look to your model and update it if necessary.

@jlandercy Thank you so much, the limit is right since the lower bound for $\int dx_2$ depends on x_1 and hence the outermost integral won't integrate to 1. In particular, the integral is not separable.

Closely related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270745/compute-probability-of-a-particular-ordering-of-normal-random-variables

Are you sure that those means are different? If the variables were identically distributed then the answer would be 1/n! from basic probability theory. Either way, the probability will be very small if n is large.

@Ishigami hi, could you set my answer as accepted please?

Based on the info from one of SO post mentioned in the comments:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270745/compute-probability-of-a-particular-ordering-of-normal-random-variables
Also same method mentioned on wiki here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation
You should convert F(X) to F(Y) in the following way:
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm, multivariate_normal


mvn = multivariate_normal



def compute_probability(thetas):
    """
        following:
        https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation


        F(X1<X2<X3<...<Xn) = F(Y1<0, Y2<0, ... Y_{n-1}<0)

        where:
            Y_i = X_{i-1} - X_{i}
            ...
        
        or what is the same:
            Y = c + BX
            mean and sigma of Y can be found based on formulas from wikipedia

    """
    
    n = len(thetas)

    # set diagonal to 1
    B = np.eye(n)

    # set right to diagonal to -1
    idx = np.arange(n-1)
    B[idx,idx+1] = -1

    # remove last row
    B = B[:-1]

    # calculate multivate sigma and mu
    sigma = np.eye(n)
    mu_new = B.dot(thetas.T)


    sigma_new = B.dot(sigma).dot(B.T)


    MVN = mvn(mean=mu_new, cov = sigma_new)

    x0 = np.zeros(shape = n-1)
    p = MVN.cdf(x = x0)
    return p


# Example usage:
theta = np.array([1, -2, 0.5])  # Example coefficient
p = compute_probability(theta)

print(p)

Outputs:
theta = (0,0)
p = 0.5

theta = (0,0,0)
p = 0.1666

theta = (100, -100)
p = 0

theta = (-100, 100)
p = 1

theta = (0,0,0,100, -100)
p = 0

